# Using Passwords in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to create an application that will connect to AWS to use certain services. If I were to hardcode the credentials in a ReactJS file, would it be publicly visible to the end user ? What is the best way to store and use such sensitive information on a ReactJS Application ?

Comment: I don't know of a way to include credentials in ReactJS without exposing them. Typically you would require your user to authenticate in some way (username/password, OAuth, etc.) and your authentication service would return a token, which you then use to access restricted services. The token has an expiration date and can be manually invalidated if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In short: No, you can't secure your client-side credentials.

[Check this article](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/)

An option

- Make the API calls server-side and then serve information to the client from there